# How to make two buttons in Microsoft Excel sort a table upon click?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have a spreadsheet with 5 columns (A-E) with names below:

1. "TEST YEAR"
2. "FORM"
3. "QUESTION"
4. "TAGS"
5. the fifth has no header title, but it still has data.

I have a separate feature in the spreadsheet that searches through the TAGS column for text and fills in the cells of a row blue if there is a match. Since I might be doing various searches at different times, I want to have two buttons that--upon clicking--will sort the 5 columns.

The first button will simply be a default sort that brings it back to normal; it sorts the table by TEST YEAR, then by FORM, then by QUESTION. The second button sorts the table first by cell color (blue), then by TEST YEAR, then by FORM, then by QUESTION.

What would such sorting macros look like, and how would I run them by clicking on buttons?

Comment: See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14859682/1698517) get you started for macro sorting and [this](http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/878-excel-insert-macro-button.html) for adding a button that triggers a macro..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code for your first sort is:

```
Sub Sort_BackToNormal()

If Sheets(1).AutoFilterMode = False Then
    Sheets(1).Range("A1:E1").AutoFilter
End If

RowCount = Sheets(1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A2:A" & RowCount), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B2:B" & RowCount), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C2:C" & RowCount), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).AutoFilter.Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

End Sub
```

The code for the second sort is:

```
Sub Sort_Color()

If Sheets(1).AutoFilterMode = False Then
    Sheets(1).Range("A1:E1").AutoFilter
End If

RowCount = Sheets(1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add(Range("D1"), xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(0, 112, 192)
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A2:A" & RowCount), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B2:B" & RowCount), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C2:C" & RowCount), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).AutoFilter.Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add(Range("D1"), xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(0, 112, 192)
End Sub
```

To make a button:

1. Insert a shape
2. Make it pretty
3. Right-click the shape and assign Macro.

Comment: It's not really working. How would you change the code of the second macro if you wanted cells of ANY color besides white to go to the top?

Comment: You will need to make sure you have the RBG numbers for the specific color you are after.

Comment: That's the thing. How would I find out the RBG of the color? Excel doesn't make it that easy. Also, what if there are multiple highlight colors? How will it order them?