# VBA Code to sort an Excel Column in Ascending Order and Expand Selection?

Tags: vba, sorting, excel

I am attempting to sort column D in ascending order in an excel file with VBA. I would like to expand the selection for all values in Column A-F.

I've used this formula as a starting point:

[sort ascending/descending vba excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14858800/sort-ascending-descending-vba-excel)

It only sorts one column and in descending order. I am having trouble finding more examples.

```
LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

If (.Range("D2").Value > .Range("D" & CStr(LastRow))) Then
    xlSort = xlAscending
End If

.Range("D2:D" & LastRow).Sort Key1:=.Range("D2"), Order1:=xlSort, Header:=xlNo, _
OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840646(v=office.15).aspx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is the answer:

```
.Range("D1") = "Index"
.Columns("A:F").Sort key1:=Range("D2"), _
order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
```

Thanks to simoco's comment!