# vba code to insert row and data in ascending order

Tags: vba, excel

I'm still quite new to VBA and I'm basically self taught. I've developed a spreadsheet for work and I need to alter my code to insert a new row where the data needs to go in ascending order. 
This is the code I am using currently to have the user form insert the data into the appropriate cells with the information that pertains to each column:

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
    'Copy input values to sheet.
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Part Number Database")
    lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    With ws
        .Cells(lRow, 1).Value = Me.txtpartnumber.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 2).Value = Me.txtdescrip.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 3).Value = Me.cbodept.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 4).Value = Me.cbomedia.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 5).Value = Me.cboeff.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 6).Value = Me.txtcfm.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 7).Value = Me.cbofm.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 8).Value = Me.cbofs.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 9).Value = Me.cbogasketsize.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 10).Value = Me.cbogasketpn.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 11).Value = Me.cbogasketloc.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 12).Value = Me.cboseal.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 13).Value = Me.cboadhesive.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 14).Value = Me.cboresin.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 15).Value = Me.cbohard.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 16).Value = Me.cbogelres.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 17).Value = Me.cbogelhard.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 18).Value = Me.cbohotmelt.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 19).Value = Me.cbofglocation.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 20).Value = Me.cbofg1.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 21).Value = Me.txtfg1.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 22).Value = Me.cbofg2.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 23).Value = Me.txtfg2.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 24).Value = Me.cbofg3.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 25).Value = Me.txtfg3.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 27).Value = Me.cbomisc1.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 28).Value = Me.txtmisc1.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 29).Value = Me.cbomisc2.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 30).Value = Me.txtmisc2.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 31).Value = Me.cbomisc3.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 32).Value = Me.txtmisc3.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 33).Value = Me.cbomisc4.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 34).Value = Me.txtmisc4.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 35).Value = Me.cbomisc5.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 36).Value = Me.txtmisc5.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 37).Value = Me.cbomisc6.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 38).Value = Me.txtmisc6.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 39).Value = Me.cbomisc7.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 40).Value = Me.txtmisc7.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 41).Value = Me.cbomisc8.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 42).Value = Me.txtmisc8.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 43).Value = Me.txtminiheight.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 44).Value = Me.txtppi.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 45).Value = Me.cboalum.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 46).Value = Me.cbowood.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 48).Value = Me.cbometal1.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 49).Value = Me.txtmetal1.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 50).Value = Me.cbometal2.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 51).Value = Me.txtmetal2.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 52).Value = Me.cbometal3.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 53).Value = Me.txtmetal3.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 54).Value = Me.cbometal4.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 55).Value = Me.txtmetal4.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 56).Value = Me.cbometal5.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 57).Value = Me.txtmetal5.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 58).Value = Me.cbometal6.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 59).Value = Me.txtmetal6.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 60).Value = Me.cbometal7.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 61).Value = Me.txtmetal7.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 62).Value = Me.cbometal8.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 63).Value = Me.txtmetal8.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 64).Value = Me.cbometal9.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 65).Value = Me.txtmetal9.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 66).Value = Me.txtheight.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 67).Value = Me.txtlength.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 68).Value = Me.txtwidth.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 69).Value = Me.txtbuild.Value
```

What I need it to do is once the user hits "Add" I need the code to sort through the first column to find where the part number needs to go and keep all the relevant cells in the same row. My first two rows are headings and my data ranges from A:BQ. 
I've tried a few different codes

```
  'Sort the rows based on the data in column A
   Columns("A").Sort key1:=Range("A2"), _
      order1:=xlAscending
```

This one moves data into the first two heading columns and actually puts the part number where it needs to be, but does not fill in the info across the whole row.

Comment: It's quite a large spreadsheet with over 5000 part numbers. I'm looking to reduce human error because the other worksheets in the book rely on these part numbers to be in ascending order in order to pull the information.

Comment: There are many similar questions, you should be able to get answer by by reading those answers. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14859682

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you data was initially sorted by the part number, and you want each insertion to fit at the appropriate row to keep the sorting valid. You might try this:

```
With ws
    lRow = 1 + Application.Match(txtpartnumber, .Columns(1), True)
    .Rows(lRow).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    .Cells(lRow, 1).value = txtpartnumber
    ' etc... Fill other data at the row
    ' ...
End With
```

Comment: I'd tend to avoid inserting rows and stick with `Sort` method both for the sake of the speed (should this ever be an issue) and not to possibly alter _surrounding_ range

Comment: Thank you A.S.H. That code worked perfectly! We enter over 20 new part numbers a week and this will definitely help with saving time.

Comment: @AshleyGoodwin you are welcome, glad to know it helped :)

Comment: Tremendously.... my boss is not very tech savy and this code will probably save me almost a good hour when it comes to training him to use this.

Answer (score 0):

if your data starts from row 2 and you have headers in row 1, then use:

```
Columns("A:N").Sort key1:=Range("A1"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
```

while if your data starts from row 2 and you don't have headers in row 1, then use:

```
Range("A2:N" & Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row).Sort key1:=Range("A2"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
```

Comment: @AshleyGoodwin, out of curiosity did you try this code?